# Ubuntu Touch for quark

Tags: porting-ubuntu-touch

I'm curious if there is a way to have ubuntu touch build for quark phones. I went through all the steps in ubuntu 16.10 and it gave me the error:

```
2017/01/03 02:32:51 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2017/01/03 02:32:52 Device is |quark|
Device quark not found on server https://system-image.ubuntu.com channel ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no Quark support,[See the list of supported devices](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices), Community and Officially ports are all listed there.

But still you can port to your favourite device. [See the details for porting to a new device](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/porting-new-device/)